# How to fix the problem of two frameworks having the same class Error?

Tags: ios, swift

Actually we have "A" framework in another third party "B" framework. So all of our network calls are using the A framework present in B framework. Can you please let me know how can I fix this problem so that our app uses the A framework always?

Comment: Make the dependency chain explicit. If you want to simply use Framework A. Add it as a direct dependency using any package manager. Calling your dependencies dependency i.e. `your-app -> B -> A` hides critical information. Incase A is not an independent framework import like `import B.A` in your file wherever you are using it.

Comment: Yes Rahul I agree, but what could be the possible solution in objective c

Answer (score 0):

You can call property like that.

```
AFramework.PropertyName

BFramework.PropertyName
```

Comment: Yeah i agree. but i was looking for how can i fix this objective c